# How can I get a Python program to kill itself using a command run through the module sys?

Tags: python, shell, kill

I want to see how a Python program could kill itself by issuing a command using the module `sys`. How could I get it to kill itself using a command of the following form?:

```
os.system(killCommand)
```

---

EDIT: emphasising for clarity

So, just to be clear, I want to have a *string* that gets run in the shell that kills the Python program.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `sys.exit()` to exit the program normally.

> Exit the interpreter by raising `SystemExit(status)`.
>      If the status is omitted or `None`, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
>      If the status is an integer, it will be used as the system exit status.
>      If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
>      exit status will be one (i.e., failure).

---

The system command to kill the interpreter itself depends on the *shell* used; if your shell is `bash` or `zsh`, you can use:

```
a@host:~$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('kill $PPID')
Terminated
a@host:~$
```

Though your actual results may vary. To be safer, you need to provide the process ID yourself:

```
>>> os.system('kill %d' % os.getpid())
```

---

If you want to just a get signal sent to your process, you can also use `os.kill()` with the process id of your process; the process id of currently running process is available from `os.getpid()`:

```
a@host:~$  python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
[1]    27248 killed     python
a@host:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on that. Your approach to getting the process identification is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

If you are in the main process (i.e. Your mail python script) you can use `os` module

```
import os
import signal

#Your Python code
os.kill(os.getpid(),signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: This solution works if you are running inside a framework like streamlit that catches `sys.exit()` but doesn't answer the OP's clarified question

Comment: I've been trying to do some nasty approach like this, (my python app uses threads and multiprocessing, everything fails to close), I want prompt to be shown on Ctrl+C, but even this one is failing, when I send `$ kill -9` from another bash console it works.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.exit(1)` will terminate the current program. The parameter is the exit status- anything but 0 indicates abnormal termination.

Comment: It won't always terminate the program, e.g. some other part of the code might catch `SystemExit`, or called from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its what that `sys.exit` is for :

> [sys.exit([arg])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit)
>
> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.
>
> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems require it to be in the range 0-127, and produce undefined results otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.
>
> Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.