# Docker: gracefully stop django server

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm using `docker` and `docker-compose`. 
Inside `docker-compose.yml` I have command that starts django server:

```
command: ["./run/web.sh"]
```

In json format command should run in exec mode. Inside `web.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec python manage.py runserver
```

When I tried to stop service with `docker-compose stop` it waited 10 seconds (default timeout) and then just kill service. In logs I've found `project_web_1 exited with code 137`.

How to stop django runserver gracefully with `docker stop`?

Comment: did you try without exec? Ex: #!/bin/sh python manage.py runserver

Comment: w/o `exec` command will run in separate context and docker will not be able to find command and send SIGTERM. Any other command works perfectly, but not `django runserver`

Comment: How about this command ? `ps aux | grep runserver | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill`

Comment: i know how to kill command manually, but don't know how to make docker kill it

Comment: make a page and kill python itself
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29065968/4883754

Comment: You know the container ID, right?  otherwise `sudo /usr/local/bin/docker ps`, get CID=12345? then just use : `ssh -t user@DockerServer "sudo /usr/local/bin/docker stop ${CID}"`, PS: you can use kill instead of stop as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, set the `stop_signal` to `SIGINT`:

```yaml
django:
  build: .
  command: ["./run/web.sh"]
  stop_signal: SIGINT
```

---

I struggled with this for a while myself…

When starting the runserver you'll notice it says "Quit the server with CONTROL-C." I took this to mean that Django's runserver is written to handle `SIGINT` (ctrl-c) and not `SIGTERM` (the signal docker sends). For me, changing the signal Docker sends to Django was easier than trying to handle `SIGTERM` in my script and exit the runserver gracefully.

Note that this depends on using `exec` in your `web.sh` script so that the signals don't get eaten by the shell – but I see you're already doing that.

Comment: Finally! I never even thought that django listens to only SIGINT.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave here the config that works for me:

yml file:

```
backend:
restart: always
container_name: django_proj
image: username/django_proj
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: ./docker/django/Dockerfile
command: /code/gunicorn-entrypoint.sh
expose:
  - 8000
```

gunicorn-entrypoint.sh which is the same thing as your sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

gunicorn -c gunicorn-config.py app_name.wsgi:application
```

Comment: As i told you any other command works fine. Including gunicorn. Only `./manage.py runserver` doesn't want to stop gracefully.